# retrieve oracle database Date column in java using Calendar Instance and compare with today's date

Tags: oracle, date

I have Oracle database with Date column in it and I want to retrieve it from recordset using Calendar since I want to compare it with today's date which is built using Calendar.

Comment: Please tell us what "Calendar" you are using? There are lots of different calendar/scheduler/diary tools, components and applications around.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you meant with retrieving the date "using Calendar", but if you are using Java, and want to read a date from database and compare it with today's date, it goes like this:

```
java.sql.Date dbDate = resultset.getDate("dateField");
java.util.Date date = new Date(dbDate.getTime());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date today = calendar.getTime(); // "today = new Date();" would work just as well
if (date.before(today)) {
    // do something
} else if (date.after(today)) {
    // do something else
}
```